# Sample NPAPI plugin in C for Linux

Tags: c, linux, firefox, npapi, chromium

I need to make a binary plugin in C that works with both Firefox and Chromium, on Linux. Where can I find a simple example of an NPAPI plugin for Linux, written in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FireBreath the cross platform/cross browser plugin project
http://firebreath.org

Answer (score 1):

I found an example at http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/modules/plugin/samples/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best I can wish for:
http://git.webvm.net/?p=npsimple (it's undocumented, but it works)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this http://code.google.com/p/npapi-file-io/.
I had tried on Ubuntu. The result is great